# Call one function in js after <END-OF-MESSAGE>

Tags: javascript, php, function

In my PHP, I have this:

```
echo "<END-OF-MESSAGE>";
```

In my JS, I want to call one function create by me after `<END-OF-MESSAGE>.`

How I can do this?

Comment: you do realise that javascript runs on the web browser and PHP runs on the server

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it only in PHP side.

```
echo  "<END-OF-MESSAGE>";
echo '<script>func(); </script>';
```